# Kafka + Spark ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to run the program specified in this IBM Developer code pattern. For now, I am only doing the local deployment https://github.com/IBM/kafka-streaming-click-analysis?cm_sp=Developer-_-determine-trending-topics-with-clickstream-analysis-_-Get-the-Code

Since it's a little old, my versions of Kafka and Scala aren't exactly what the code pattern calls for. The versions I am using are:

Scala: 2.4.6
Kafka 0.10.2.1

At the last step, I get the following error:

```
ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = f4dfe12f-1c99-427e-9f75-91a77f6e51a7, 
runId = c9744709-2484-4ea1-9bab-28e7d0f6b511] terminated with error
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException
```

Along with the execution tree

The steps I am following are as follows:

```
1. Start Zookeeper
2. Start Kafka
3. cd kafka_2.10-0.10.2.1
4. tail -200 data/2017_01_en_clickstream.tsv | bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list ip:port --topic clicks --producer.config=config/producer.properties
```

I have downloaded the dataset and stored it in a directory called data inside of the kafka_2.10-0.10.2.1 directory

```
cd $SPARK_DIR
bin/spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.6
```

Since SPARK_DIR wasn't set during the Spark installation, I am navigating the the directory containing spark to run this command

```
scala> import scala.util.Try

scala> case class Click(prev: String, curr: String, link: String, n: Long)

scala> def parseVal(x: Array[Byte]): Option[Click] = {
    val split: Array[String] = new Predef.String(x).split("\\t")
    if (split.length == 4) {
      Try(Click(split(0), split(1), split(2), split(3).toLong)).toOption
    } else
      None
  }

scala> val records = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
                  .option("subscribe", "clicks")
                  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
                  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").load()

scala>
val messages = records.select("value").as[Array[Byte]]
                 .flatMap(x => parseVal(x))
                 .groupBy("curr")
                 .agg(Map("n" -> "sum"))
                 .sort($"sum(n)".desc)
val query = messages.writeStream
          .outputMode("complete")
          .option("truncate", "false")
          .format("console")
          .start()
```

The last statement, query=... is giving the error mentioned above. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yiou can use :paste & CTRL<D> for inserting logic into the shell.

Comment: manual misleading it appears.

Answer (score 0):

A required library or dependency for interacting with Apache Kafka is missing, so you may need to install the missing library or update to a compatible version

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33797822)